# Comparing hashes when entering Excel password

Tags: c#, excel, hash, passwords

here's my problem:

1. User inputs a password in the Options section of the program.
2. The password is hashed (MD5) and stored in the registry.
3. The program is ran, an Excel spreadsheet is created, and password protected using the hashed value that is stored in the registry.
4. The user opens the spreadsheet, and is prompted to enter the password.
5. The user enters the password, but it fails no matter what.

The reason it fails is because the user is inputting the password in cleartext, yet the function is comparing it to a hashed value, which it will obviously error out.

How can I hash the Excel password that is being entered when accessing the spreadsheet in order to compare it with the stored hash in the Registry?

Any ideas on working around this would also be appreciated.

I'm writing this in C# using Excel Interop...

Thanks...

Woody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program will have to provide the password, because the user doesn't know what it is!

Fortunately, the `Excel.Workbooks.Open` method takes an argument permitting you to specify the password required. So your code could get the hashed password from the registry (or from wherever you are storing it) and then open the wokrbook via code:

```
string fileName = @"C:\...";
string password = GetHashedPasswordFromRegistry();

Excel.Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open( 
    fileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Type.Missing,
    password, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

I think this should do what you're looking for? Let us know how it goes...

Mike

Comment: No problem, Woody. In C# 3.0 we're forced to provide every single argument, so it's easy to overlook. The good news is that it's there! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public static class Helpers
{
    public static Guid GetHash(string password)
    {
        return new Guid(new MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password.Trim())));
    }
}
```

usage:

```
string hash = Helpers.GetHash("password").ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick comment. But I think you might not understand what I'm saying -- I'm trying to hash the value that is inputted into Excel when the spreadsheet is being opened. I know of no way to do that without being able to hook into Excel in some way -- in essence, during that authentication... I know how to hash variables -- it's the issue of hashing the inputted password that is inputted into Excel's dialog box...

Comment: My bad. I don't know the answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd don't really know what Excel interop can do, but in standard C# / .NET the quickest way to hash a password in MD5 format is use:

```
string hashedPassword = System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile("password", "MD5")
```

See [FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.hashpasswordforstoringinconfigfile.aspx). (Yes, it's a stupid method name in the wrong namespace!).